# Getting data from multiple tables in a belongs_to and has_many relationship in Rails

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, rails-activerecord

I'm a PHP programmer coming over to Rails and just can't seem to figure this simply Active Record call out. Basically, I have two tables, `exchanges` and `markets`. They are as follows:

```
class Market < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :date_created, :exchange_id, :market_name, :market_year

  belongs_to :exchange 

end

class Exchange < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :date_created, :exchange_name, :exchange_type

  has_many :markets

end
```

I want to retrieve all of the `Markets`, and in the same call, all of the `exchange` information about those `markets`.

In PHP, this would have looked like: `"SELECT * FROM markets, exchanges WHERE markets.id>0"`

All I can do is either select all of the Markets and then individually query to look up the Exchange information about each of those Markets:

```
market = Market.first
exchange = Exchange.where(:id => market.exchange_id)
```

There has to be an easier way. Does this make sense?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want all the markets, including their exchange then do:

```
@markets = Market.includes(:exchange)
```

If you want a single exchange and all its markets then do:

```
@exchange = Exchange.includes(:markets).first
@markets = @exchange.markets
```

If you need to pass in the id manually then do:

```
@markets = Market.where("exchange_id = ?", put_id_here)
```

Here's some more info about [eager loading associations in Rails](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#eager-loading-associations).